# How to know when Android device is plugged into USB port?

Tags: c#, android, .net, wpf, winforms

How can I tell if an Android device is plugged in to a USB port? I've seen many code samples that detect when any USB device is plugged in, but I can't use that. I need to be able to detect an Android device.

Comment: @beworker How is that the answer? My question is about C#, .NET Framework - Not Java. You obviously didn't read that question or its title or answers. It's not the answer.

Comment: @Tommy this sounds strange, but look into IKVM. It allows you to run Java code through C#. You may be able to leverage existing Java libraries for this.

Comment: Thank you @ashes, I'll definitely look into that.

Comment: You question is not clear at all. You said in a comment that your question is about C# but you do not mention it in your question. Are you using Xamarin? or is it a PC app in C# that you are coding? There is a lack of informations and details. Please use the edit link button and adds anything relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Question isn't clear to me, do you have to detect every Android device, or you want to detect just your private device?

Though, this may not be what are you searching for, but the easiest approach you could try would be to invoke command *adb devices* on USB device connection event and parse the output. I can't give much code right now, because of limited time I have, but take a look at 
[WinUSB C#](http://www.lvr.com/winusb.htm)

You can start process and parse its output.

```
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
psi.FileName = @"C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe";
psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
psi.RedirectStandardError = true;
psi.RedirectStandardInput = true;
psi.UseShellExecute = false;
psi.CreateNoWindow = true;

System.Diagnostics.Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo = psi;
p.OutputDataReceived += p_DataReceived;
p.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
p.Start();
p.BeginOutputReadLine();
p.BeginErrorReadLine();

p.StandardInput.WriteLine("adb devices");
p.StandardInput.WriteLine("exit");
p.WaitForExit();

static void p_DataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
// Manipulate received data here
        Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
// if no devices, then there will be only "List of devices attached: "
}
```

Once again, it's only a fast example and there should be a better solution for it. You could check Device ID upon connection, but it makes another problem - how to know that this ID is ID of an Android device?

**EDIT:** You also have to add ADB executable to your PATH environmental variable.

**EDIT2:** If you don't want to rely on PATH, you could provide ADB with your application and run it from app's directory, getting it with `Application.StartupPath`

**EDIT3:** Another drawback is that you have to enable USB Debugging in your Android device before ADB can detect it.

Comment: One caveat: this requires `adb` to be on the path. That may not always be true.

Comment: Thank you @MrCiastexx this is more than enough :-) Would it be safe to assume that instead of "parsing", I could just to something like `if(e.Data.ToString().Contains("android")) { // An android device is connected. Do something. }`? It's cool if I can't, it's just that I'm not bothered which kind of Android device is connected :)

Comment: @Tommy that'll probably work. The best thing to do is try it out and see. I'm sure you can get your hands on a couple of Android devices to test with.

Comment: @Tommy this will work, but not always, for example, ADB output for my Android device is `MedfieldXXXXXXXX    device`. You should parse every line starting from the second for that keyword `device`. This will ensure you have connected a proper Android device.